# hibernate JPA query works only with namespace

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have a JAR which contains only my model which are annotated classes. Then the application which loads the JAR.

In the persistence.xml of the app I have:

`<jar-file> my jar </jar-file>`

and in the properties:

`<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />`

That works. The entities are detected and this query works fine:

```
List<Event> events = em.createQuery(
"from com.my.namespace.model.Event", Event.class).getResultList();
```

However I absolutely need to have the namespace in the query... If I do:

```
List<Event> events = em.createQuery("from Event", Event.class).getResultList();
```

Then I get this exception:

```
Event is not mapped [from Event]
```

What is even more frustrating is that I give to JPA the class, Event.class as the second argument of my call. The Java codes imports the right package.

How do I get the JPAQL/HQL to "import" the right package to see that entity without needing to explicitely type the namespace?

**Update:** here is Event.java if it helps.. it is as trivial as it gets:

```
package com.my.namespace.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name="events")
@SequenceGenerator(name="events_id_seq", sequenceName="events_id_seq")
public class Event {

    @Id @Column(name="id") @GeneratedValue(generator="events_id_seq")
    private Long mId;

    @Column(name="title")
    private String mTitle;

    public Long getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post Event.java, how you mapped Table and Entity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Entity(name="events")` is  the culprit

it has to be

```
          @Entity
          @Table(name="events")
```

If you intenteded events as db table name. Otherwise use `events` in your query instead of `Event`

Comment: thank you for telling me what I intended to type, separating the @Table annotation. A bit shocked because that worked fine with hibernate-core.

Answer (score 2):

Since your name of the entity is "events" (from @Entity(name="events")) you should select from "events" not "event".

```
List<Event> events = em.createQuery("from events", Event.class).getResultList();
```

should therefore work

Comment: no, what you should type in HQL/JPAQL is the class name, besides as I wrote it works with the namespace. I tried your suggestion anyway and it doesn't work, with and without the namespace.

Comment: is it `from Events` or `from events` ?

Comment: I understand now, you are right. This mapping worked as-is with hibernate-core! I thought there is no difference between hibernate-core annotationsand JPA annotations...